# Early references to Sri Andal as Bhudevi

Tags: sri-vaishnava, andal

I know Sri Andal is one of the 12 Azwars, and also Sri Vaishnavism takes HER as an incarnation of Bhudevi. I have some questions about this -

1) Even though Sri Andal is one of the 12 Azwars, as per the Sri Vaishnavism system, SHE enjoys a special status as the consort of Lord Sriman NArAyaNA - is this correct?
2) Have Azwars referred to HER as Bhudevi in their works? Though I understand many Azwars lived before the time of Sri Andal (so if such references are found, that would raise the question about the timing and dates)
3) Did either Sri Ramanujacharya, or Sri Desika, or one of the later acharyas of Sri Vaishnavism portray Sri Andal this way?
4) What is the earliest reference available to us, that talks about Sri Andal as an incarnation of Bhudevi?

Response much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Even though Sri Andal is one of the 12 Azwars, 
>   as per the Sri Vaishnavism system, SHE enjoys a 
>   special status as the consort of Lord Sriman NArAyaNA 
>   - is this correct?

Correct.

> Did either Sri Ramanujacharya, or Sri Desika,
>   or one of the later acharyas of Sri Vaishnavism 
>   portray Sri Andal as Bhudevi?

Yes. Periyavachan Pillai (post Ramanuja) makes several references to her as an incarnation of Bhumi Devi in his Tiruppavai commentaries. Vedanta Desika has many works such as Goda Stuti and Rashya Shikamani in which he does the same. Thirukkannamangai Andan (pre-Ramanuja) also refers to her as a "companion of Lakshmi".

> What is the earliest reference available to us, 
>   that talks about Sri Andal as an incarnation of Bhudevi?

That would be either Thirukkannamangai Andan's verse or Periyavachan Pillai's commentaries.

On a separate note, the yajurvedic bhUsUktam contains a phrase (trigmshaddhAm avirAjati)that is considered to be a foretelling of Bhumi devi's upcoming incarnation as Andal and writing the Tiruppavai.

Comment: Thank you @hashable